is there a shortcut for "cursor to selected"
There's an older post from 8 years ago that says:
Edit Mode
Shift 2
Right click on "cursor to selected"
But this doesnt work.
There's also an answer to "add to the quick menu" but I cannot make that work either.  If you're like me, you use "cursor to selected" almost more than any other action.  I cannot believe this is so difficult.  What is the way to create a key command for this action?
Thanks

Shift+S? Thats the default to open that menu. Not sure what version you're using, but I'd always recommend enabling the 3D View Pie Menu addon; it's built in, and uses this shortcut with an additional bunch of options as well.

Shift S pulls up Snap Pie, then requires a click to Snap Cursor to Selected.  I want Direct Access.  No Snap Pie Menu.   Im using 4.3

You can add your own shortcut to an operator by going to the shortcut in the menus and right-clicking, then clicking Assign Shortcut.

